# Adding images next to radio buttons in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I am making a GUI in wxpython.
I want to place images next to radio buttons.
How should i do that in wxpython?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using wx.ToggleButton with bitmap labels if you are using 2.9, or one of the bitmap toggle button classes in wx.lib.buttons if you are still on 2.8.  You can then implement the "radio button" functionality yourself by untoggling all other buttons in the group when one of them is toggled.  Using the bitmap itself as the radio button will look nicer and will save space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean. Are you wanting images instead of the actual radio button itself? That is not supported. If you want an image in addition to the radio button, then just use a group of horizontal box sizers or one of the grid sizers. Add the image and then the radio button. And you're done!

Comment: Oh sorry if i was not clear enough. But,usually there's text next to radio button but i want image next placed next to radio button instead of text.And that image will be static only.

Comment: The RadioButton widget doesn't support that. I would recommend rolling your own or see Robin's answer

Answer (score 0):

I am satisfied with the following:

- image icon is left to the radio button,
- click on the image activates radion button.

It seems that usability does not suffer.

```
def make_radio_with_icon(parent_window, bitmap, label):
  sizer = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
  sizer.Add(bitmap)
  r = wx.RadioButton(parent_window, label=label)
  sizer.Add(r)
  def on_click(evt):
    r.SetValue(1)
  bitmap.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, on_click)
  return sizer
```

By analogue, you can implement the ordering: radion button itself, image, label.